# Seeking iPhone/iPad JavaScript/jQuery libs, techniques & tutorials

Tags: theming

Client wants iPad & iPhone support for a webapp that has at least one form where DOM elements are dragged around on a (Raphael) Canvas (JavaScript rendered graphic).

Currently, the touch-unfriendly interface to drag items around uses mouse-hover and other mouse states to handle the drag-items interface. I know I'll need a completely different approach for touch screen devices, and am wondering if any fellow Drupal developers have posted their breadcrumbs as they faced this.

Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 does not matter, since this is at the JavaScript layer unless the possible solution requires jQuery only available in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I know of that's close to what you want is on [Eric London's Drupal blog](http://thedrupalblog.com/configuring-mobile-drupal-site-and-making-your-theme-mobile-friendly) where he talks about themes and redirects for mobile versions of Drupal websites.  I'd be interested in knowing more about this too, sorry that I couldn't be of more help.